# Batch rename files by adding +1 to prefix number in a filename

Tags: regex, macos, terminal, batch-processing

So, my question is: **How to add +1 to the prefix number in a filename?**

The goal is to go rename multiple files so that they go from this:

```
1_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
2_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
3_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
4_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
13_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
18_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
19_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
20_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
```

To this:

```
2_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
3_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
4_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
5_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
14_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
19_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
20_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
21_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf
```

---

---

I'm not very experienced with terminal at all. I was able to find [examples for removing prefix number](https://superuser.com/questions/272237/remove-numbers-from-filenames-in-mac-os-x). It works fine, but when I try to replace something by using regex, I can't get very close.

So after first trying and failing horribly at correctly regexing this in the terminal, I thought I'd give it a try in javascript.

I was able to get it <kbd>[working in javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/6ZCxJ/1/)</kbd> `/[0-9]*(?=_)/`.

So, my best guess for terminal is this, except it doesn't quite work.:

```
cd  {TESTFOLDER}

REGEX=[0-9]*(?=_)

for name in *; do mv -v "$name" "${name/$REGEX/$(( ${name/$REGEX}+1 ))}"; done
```

Comment: for the regex you should probably match the start of the line or string instead of using a lookahead e.g. ^[0-9]*

Comment: @user3334690 I'm probably doing it wrong, but it doesn't seem to make much difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using BASH string manipulation:

```
s='1_loremipsum_and_stuff_2013.pdf'
mv "$s" "$((${s%%_*}+1))_${s#*_}"
```

**EDIT:** Based on discussion below you can use

```
while read f; do 
   mv "$f" "$((${f%%_*}+1))_${f#*_}"
done < <(sort -t_ -rnk1,2 <(printf "%s\n" *_*))
```

Comment: I was not exactly sure how you wanted me to run this, so I did it this way `for name in *; do mv -v "$name" "$((${name%%_*}+1))_${name#*_}"; done` Strangely enough, it kept replacing the files, until I had only one file in the folder.

Comment: If you run same command again it will increment first number again. But if directory has only one file it will stop after renaming first file.

Comment: Ok, but I had 12 files and after running that, I had 1 file. I guess it happened because it kept renaming the same file or something.

Comment: Are your files named in sequential order i.e. `"1_something", "2_something"`?

Comment: Just like I said my original post. There may be gaps here and there, where the number jumps from say, 8 to 11. But aside from that the rest of the filename is the same for every file. So yea, the issue seems to be how the filenames are identical, if you don't count the prefix.

Comment: Seems to be working just fine. There is one thing I had overlooked.  There may be cases where random files have one or more 0 in front of the number (`03_example.pdf, 4_example.pdf, 5_example.pdf, 6_example.pdf, 007_example.pdf, 024_example.pdf `). In those cases this script either breaks, or does nothing but removes the 0s. This is not a huge deal for me as there are so few of them that they can be manually changed, but I'm afraid that it might create a human error... if I miss one of them.

Comment: Yes `007_example.pdf` will become `8_example.pdf` due to number increment.

Comment: Not consistently, it doesn't. Sometimes it seems to work, but other times it won't. It seems to change all the time. I've gotten these results `030` becomes `25`, `040` becomes `33`, `09` stays `09`, `01` stays `01`, also couple times some random error.. It doesn't seem to have much logic when it comes to this scenario...

Comment: It is because `030` is considered an octal number and becomes `24` in decimal. After increment it becomes `25`.

Comment: So to patch up the shortcoming of this script, which is great, don't get me wrong, I decided to regex out the leading zeros first before running this script. So the way I did it might be slightly dumb, but I ended up removing the leading zeros with nameChanger _( a free mac batch renaming app, that I usually use anyways )_ with the regex [`^[0]*(?=[1-9])`](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/6ZCxJ/3/). Because I wasn't able to get that same regex working in terminal. I guess I just don't understand the flavor of regex it's running...

Comment: I also use Mac and have installed `rename` script using `home brew` for this renaming.

Answer (score 0):

To perform your exact example in bash - simply do

```
for f in *.pdf; 
  do \
  echo mv "$f" "$((${f%%_*}+1))_${f#*_}"; # remove echo for real run
done
```

However, many people may have letter prefixes before their intergers, such as for SQL migration files. Example: `V1__some_awesome_migration.sql`

In that case, you will want to trim your prefix before the integers you want to increment. To do so, you can assign the trimmed strings to variables, such as with:

```
for f in *.pdf; 
  do  \
  prefix="${f:0:1}"
  suffix="${f:1}"; 
  echo mv "$f" "$prefix$((${suffix%%_*}+1))_${suffix#*_}"; # remove echo for real run
done
```